# What does PyPI error "Upload failed (400): summary: Multiple lines are not allowed" mean?

Tags: python, pypi

I just tried to upload a new version of a package to PyPI, but got this error:

```
$ python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload
…
Writing pip2pi-0.7.0/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'pip2pi-0.7.0' (and everything under it)
running upload
Submitting /Users/wolever/code/pip2pi/dist/pip2pi-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Upload failed (400): summary: Multiple lines are not allowed.
error: Upload failed (400): summary: Multiple lines are not allowed.
```

What does it mean? And how can I fix it?

Previous versions of this package uploaded without issue.

The code I'm trying to upload: https://github.com/wolever/pip2pi/tree/a026f05a265a6f8c7fb7a5c4cf6484b9ede77761

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must have been a change made to PyPI at some point disallowing multiline descriptions. Removing the newlines in the `description="…"` field of `setup.py` fixed the issue: https://github.com/wolever/pip2pi/commit/6f24cec93344fdc133e97ead5f81224e7eb4a249